# how can I get these elements to tuck into eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to get a look like pinterest, where the elements (pics w/ captions) slide into each other. There are two distinct rows here, however, I need the pics with captions to slide into each other.

http://pureformenyc.com/inspiration/

Comment: And what's your problem, where are you stuck? What have you tried (if anything) and what went wrong?

Comment: This is not question, this description fo some thing. From your post hard to tell you any solutution because you did ask nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) layout plugin.